# Making a Letter pattern output horizontally

Tags: java

Hello I'm new to java and I'm trying to make a pattern that output horizontally but so far it is always outputting vertically which is making me frustrating lol. I have been trying to find ways to arrange the output horizontally but I still can't make it adjust itself. I'm also really scared at changing my code because of the "brackets" it's making me really confused. Can anyone lend me a hand? It would really be helpful

```
public class LetterPattern_DAMPAC {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for (int patternD1=0; patternD1<7; patternD1++)
        {
            for (int patternD2=0; patternD2<4; patternD2++)
            {
                if (patternD2==0 || patternD2==patternD1+1 || patternD1+patternD2==7 || patternD1*patternD2==9)
                {
                    System.out.print(" "+"D");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(" "+" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int patternA1 = 0; patternA1<7; patternA1++)
        {
            for (int patternA2=7; patternA2>patternA1; patternA2--)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int patternA3=0; patternA3<=patternA1; patternA3++)
            {
                if (patternA1==4 || patternA3==0 || patternA3==patternA1)
                {
                    System.out.print(" "+ "A");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(" "+ " ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int patternM1=0; patternM1<6; patternM1++)
        {
            for (int patternM2=0; patternM2<7; patternM2++)
            {
                if (patternM2==0 || patternM2==6 || (patternM1==patternM2 || patternM1+patternM2==6) && patternM1<4)
                {
                    System.out.print("M"+" ");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(" "+" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int patternP1=0; patternP1<7; patternP1++)
        {
            for (int patternP2=0; patternP2<3; patternP2++)
            {
                if (patternP2==0 || patternP2==patternP1+1 || patternP1+patternP2==4)
                {
                    System.out.print("P"+" ");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int patternAA1=0; patternAA1<7; patternAA1++)
        {
            for (int patternAA2=7; patternAA2>patternAA1; patternAA2--)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int patternAA3=0; patternAA3<=patternAA1; patternAA3++)
            {
                if (patternAA1==4 || patternAA3==0 || patternAA3==patternAA1)
                {
                    System.out.print(" "+"A");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(" "+" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int patternC1=0; patternC1<7; patternC1++)
        {
            for (int patternC2 = 0; patternC2<7; patternC2++)
            {
                if (((patternC1==6 || patternC1==0) && patternC2>0) || (patternC1<6 && patternC1>0 && patternC2<1))
                {
                    System.out.print(" "+"C");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what your issue is and what you are asking but if you have a problem with the output being vertical then you shouldn’t use `System.out.println();` since it adds a line break.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you add the output you are currently getting, and the output you want to your question?

Comment: `I'm also really scared at changing my code because of the "brackets" it's making me really confused` - If this is _your_ code why does it confuse you? Don't you know what you've written? Also I don't see any brackets that would be problematic - just try it.

Comment: You should store the every character result in a array horizontally, after all character results have stored, print the array.